# jquery center image after zooming in overflow:auto container

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, overflow, zooming

I need help centering an image inside a container with overflow:auto after enlarging the image width and height.

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RCw4T/1

The underlying idea is that when the user centers a section of the image inside the container and clicks zoom, the image enlarges but still remains centered on that section. that way you can continue zooming in on a section without having to hunt for the section after every click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks the script prevents giving `top` and `left` values for less than 0, if you change the logic to allow values < 0 you should get a centered zoom...

Change this

```
iTop = (iNewH < ipH ? (ipH / 2) - (iNewH / 2) : 0);
iLeft = (iNewW < ipW ? (ipW / 2) - (iNewW / 2) : 0);
```

To this

```
iTop = (ipH / 2) - (iNewH / 2);
iLeft = (ipW / 2) - (iNewW / 2);
```

**EDIT:**

to allow scrolling to all parts of the image (ie no negative positioning) you can use the [ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) jquery plugin

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/RCw4T/26/)

something like

```
if (iNewH > $container.height() || iNewW > $container.width()) {
    $container.scrollTo({ 
        top:(iNewH - $container.height()) / 2, 
        left:(iNewW - $container.width()) / 2 
    });
}
```

might consider changing the above logic to handle height/width separately, I'll leave that to you.

Comment: but I don't want the image to get cut off by going negative top and left. The scrollbars should move to the necessary locations to make it centered in the frame.

Comment: good idea, but I implemented it and it still not scrolling to the desired location.

Comment: in what way is it not working, scrolling to the wrong part of the image or not scrolling at all? you included the ScrollTo plugin?

Comment: it is scrolling to the wrong part of the image, even in your fiddle example it is not scrolling to the right location.  And yes, I included scrollTo

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/jhDhM/

It might need some tweaking.

Here is the js code in the fiddle:

```
var zoomFactor = 1;

$('#container img').click(function(e) {

    var iScaler = 1.5,
        iH = $(this).height(),
        iW = $(this).width(),
        iNewH = iH * iScaler,
        iNewW = iW * iScaler,
        $parent = $(this).parent(),
        zoomPosX = (e.clientX - ($parent.width() / 2)) / zoomFactor,
        zoomPosY = (e.clientY - ($parent.height() / 2)) / zoomFactor;
    zoomFactor *= iScaler;
    $(this).css({
        top: zoomPosY + 'px',
        left: zoomPosX + 'px',
        width: iNewW + 'px',
        height: iNewH + 'px'
    });

});
```

---

In your version: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/RCw4T/10/

That fixes the less than greater than mix up and you should go right centered all of the time :-)